# get a slicer to show correctly data from dim table when flittering from a fact table

Tags: filter, powerbi, fact, fact-table

I have fact table of tickets.  There is a field in that table called ownerSK which has the owner of the ticket.  This is in the form of there email address.  There is also a dim table called Employee which has ownerSK and EmployeeName. This table is linked to a fact table via ownersk. The link between the two is 1(dim) to many(fact) link.

I have a column chart to show a distinct count of owners of tickets by day of week.  Based on resolved date(from date table linked to resolved date in fact table).  That works however I want to produce a slicer list of those values.  With there full name from the employee dim table.  Rather than there email address from ownerSK field in fact table.

It works fine using ownersk field on my drill through page but not on the actual page.  It does not work at all if I try and use employee name in my drill through. (Without the need to turn on by directional filtering which I believe might fix the issue)

I thought there might be away to use DAX in the filter on visual for the slicer.  To filter out just the employees.   However I've not been able to get this to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?